# Maximum Likelihood with 2 Samples

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood

I would like to know if my workings are correct.

I have for $\theta\in(0,1)$,

$$ f_\theta(x) = \begin{cases}\theta^2&,\text{ if }-1 \leq x \le 0 \\ 1- \theta^2 &, \text{ if } \;\,0 \leq x \le 1\\ 0\; &,\text{ otherwise}\end{cases} $$

$X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n $ are iid.

Say $a$  is the number of  which are negative $X_i<0$ and $b$ be the number of  which are non-negative $X_i>0$. (Note that the total number of samples is $ n = a + b$ and be careful not to mix up the roles of $a$  and $b$ .)

What is the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\theta}^{MLE}$  of $\theta$?

So I calculated the Likelihood function which :

$$L(\theta) = (\theta^2)^{a}  (1- \theta^2)^{b}  $$

Differentiating after putting in log with respect to $\theta$ gives me $$\hat{\theta}^{MLE} = \sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}} $$

Is my reasoning correct? Thank you very much.

Comment: That seems plausible: the natural estimator for $\theta^2$ is $\dfrac{a}{a+b}$

Comment: What you did is correct.